# Error With Simple Function Using setline()

Tags: vimscript, functions

I'm trying to start writing some Vim Script, and I've come across this issue.

```
fu Test()
    call setline(1, getline("."))
endf

autocmd InsertCharPre * call Test()
```

This is in my `.vimrc`. When I type something, I get an `E523` error. Looking that up in help shows that it's liked with having `secure` on. I checked and I have it off, so I'm stumped as to what the issue is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `:h insertcharpre`:

> It is not allowed to change the text |textlock|.

---

You need to delay the change with a one-shot autocmd, for example until the next `TextChangedI` is fired:

```
fu! Test() abort
    au TextChangedI * ++once call setline(1, getline('.'))
endfu
augroup test
    au!
    au InsertCharPre * call Test()
augroup END
```

The `++once` flag is provided by the patch [8.1.1113](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.1113). If you don't have it, make the autocmd clear itself:

```
fu! Test() abort
    augroup setline_on_textchangedi
        au!
        au TextChangedI * call setline(1, getline('.')) | au! setline_on_textchangedi
    augroup END
endfu
augroup test
    au!
    au InsertCharPre * call Test()
augroup END
```

Note that `TextChangedI` is not fired after you insert a character while the popup menu is visible.
If that's an issue, you need to also listen to `TextChangedP` provided by the patch [8.0.1494](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.1494):

```
au TextChangedI,TextChangedP * ++once call setline(1, getline('.'))
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Or just use a timer:

```
fu! Test() abort
    call timer_start(0, {-> setline(1, getline('.'))})
endfu
augroup test
    au!
    au InsertCharPre * call Test()
augroup END
```

---

If you don't need to listen to `InsertCharPre`, then the textlock issue disappears, and the code can be simplified:

```
augroup test
    au!
    au TextChangedI,TextChangedP * call setline(1, getline('.'))
augroup END
```

---

For more information, see:

```
:h textlock
:h insertcharpre
:h textchangedi
:h textchangedp
:h autocmd-once
:h timer_start(
```

Comment: Of course the one thing I didn't look at, thank you.