# Usage of a autocmd to write into a buffer - E523: Not allowed here

Tags: autocmd

I am trying to make a plugin, which will be displaying a content of registers in the side bar and updating this side bar at every register's changing.
To accomplish this task I decided to set a hook on the `TextYankPost` event and to write a changed register's dictionary into the side bar window when this event happens.

But there is a problem - the `autocmd` doesn't allow writing commands like `:put` inside a called function, so when I do:

```
function! Write_to_buffer()
    put ='hello'
endfunction

autocmd TextYankPost * :call Write_to_buffer()
```

I get an error

```
Error detected while processing function Write_to_buffer:
line    1:
E523: Not allowed here
```

Without a writing command all works as expected:

```
function! Write_to_buffer()
    echo 'hello'
endfunction

autocmd TextYankPost * :call Write_to_buffer()
```

The `:h E523` says:

> When on, ":autocmd", shell and write commands are not allowed in
>   ".vimrc" and ".exrc" in the current directory and map commands are
>   displayed.  Switch it off only if you know that you will not run into
>   problems, or when the 'exrc' option is off.  On Unix this option is
>   only used if the ".vimrc" or ".exrc" is not owned by you.  This can be
>   dangerous if the systems allows users to do a "chown".  You better set
>   'secure' at the end of your ~/.vimrc then.

Both `secure` and `exrc` options are **off** in my case:

```
echo printf('secure = %s, exrc = %s', &secure, &exrc)
" Output: secure = 0, exrc = 0
```

**So the questions:**

1. Is the usage of the `autocmd` for tracking register changes right/optimal?
2. How can a function called by the `autocmd` be used for writing into a buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the usage of the autocmd for tracking register changes right/optimal?

Well, there are many ways to change a register. Something like `:let @0 = 'Some text'` will change the register 0 just like `yank` does. So you can't make it truly robust. That's simply impossible, I believe (unless you poll the timer, but that does not seem like a nice way to deal with this either).

> How can a function called by the autocmd be used for writing into a buffer?

This problem doesn't apply to autocommands in general (i.e. you **can** write to buffer while inside an autocommand). It's specific to this individual autocommand. A quote from `:h TextYankPost`: "It is not allowed to change the buffer text, see :h textlock". So, for example, you can save "a pending update" in a list, and apply it later (maybe from within `:h CursorHold`, or `:h SafeStateAgain` or by a timer etc.).

Comment: I found a way to fix `E523` error while `TextYankPost` happens [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21459/14024). I applied a `timer_start` trick and printing to a buffer have started to work. Now I am thinking about of two variants: 1) To find a way to catch a `:let @0 = 'Some text'` case. One of my thoughts was catching a `:let` command execution in the command line by `CmdwinLeave` event but it haven't worked. 2) Usage of `timer_start` with a `repeat` option. This way I can check the reg's dictionary every second. What do you think? Is the first variant (catching `let` command) possible?

Comment: @MiniMax No, I don't think that will make much sense. There are standalone scripts/plugins manipulating registers; also CmdlineLeave is triggered before command execution, and parsing by hand is very complicated: say, `setreg()` can be a part of an arbitrary VimScript expression, and so on. So if you're really going to implement such thing, you'll come to timer-based update sooner or later.